# Unable to ping server at localhost:8180

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Hi guys im using intellij and maven and i was working on my code but when I try to ru it locally im getting this issue, I checked all the configuration but I dont know exactly why this issue appear

Comment: Error message says "Duplicate resource". So because you have coding error the app did not start.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when IDE can not connect to mentioned port. It is most likely specified in run debug configuration. This may happen because the port has already been occupied by another process (e.g. There is already Tomcat instance running).

Also if you have antivirus/firewall make sure it does not block IDE process from making connections on localhost: make sure to exclude IDE process, IDE installation home, IDE [configuration/system](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs) folders, project and library directories from the scan. Try restarting the PC, try using different JMX port in Run/Debug Configuration.